# Add multiple TimeSpans together with datejs

Tags: addition, timespan, datejs

I'm using the JavaScript library datejs and in particularly the TimeSpan class.

I've got it all working great for one TimeSpan.  However I need it to add together the results of multiple TimeSpans on the page. My code is below:

```
var monTimeSpan = new TimeSpan(Date.parse($("#monFinish").val()) - Date.parse($("#monStart").val()))

var tueTimeSpan = new TimeSpan(Date.parse($("#tueFinish").val()) - Date.parse($("#tueStart").val()))
```

These work great but I need to add the result of the Tuesday TimeSpan to the Monday one.

Any help would be great.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The `TimeSpan` object includes the `.add()` function.

The following sample demonstrates adding two `TimeSpan` objects together.

**Example**

```
var t1 = new TimeSpan(Date.today().add(5).days() - Date.today());

var t2 = new TimeSpan(Date.today().add(10).days() - Date.today());

var total = t1.add(t2);

total.days // 15
```